# Configuring 'simplest' node.js + socket.IO + Express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

Realized after setting up a simple node.js socket.IO server that it isn't sufficient to handle even the simplest webpages containing script tags.

So I investigating express which is a simple web framework for node.js.

After looking thru the express documentation http://expressjs.com/guide.html
I was still confused as to how I simply combine express with socket.IO on a node.js server.

Couple hours of googling later I came across this tutorial
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-express-a-node-js-framework-and-set-up-socket-io-on-a-vps

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server); // this tells socket.io to use our express server

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', routes.index);


console.log("Express server listening on port 3000");
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('A new user connected!');
    socket.emit('info', { msg: 'The world is round, there is no up or down.' });
});
```

My question is, would anyone reading this configure their server differently?
I don't need anything special, no session handling etc, just the ability to serve html pages containing links to external CSS and javascript files.

Comment: You may not need to configure the template engine if you serve only static resources

Comment: Socket.io has nothing to do with simple web pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the replies. Finally have something that works and am posting so someone else may benefit. My first attempt(above) was obviously NOT the simplest solution:)

```
//npm install express
//npm install socket.io
var express = require('express');
var server = express.createServer();

server
    .use( server.router )
    .use( express.static(__dirname+'/public') )
    .get('/api', function(req, res) {
        res.write('API');
    });

server=server.listen(3000);

var io = require('socket.io');
var socket = io.listen(server);

socket.on('connection', function (client){
  // new client is here!


});
```

Comment: Has no method createServer();

Comment: @Ryanb58 I assume this is because express api has changed across the versions. The post should mention for which version it worked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the first `app.configure` wrapper but leave it's contents. It is useless in general, but especially if you don't pass an argument to it.
2. Remove `methodOverride` and `bodyParser` as you aren't using them

Comment: thanks. what about routes? I was getting an error saying it was undefined so I commented out the 2 lines referencing it. But still something wrong as when I load my test index.html page it displays 'Cannot GET'

Comment: I think the remaining issue is where the server is pointing. I have an index.html file in the same folder as my app.'s and in the browser loading 'localhost:3000'. It returns 'Cannot GET' so there is a 404.

Comment: ok figured I'm missing the routes module so did a npm install routes, but now 'express/lib/outer/index.js is throwing an error! I give up...will ditch express and try something simpler like send

Comment: Aye. Slow down. So `'./routes'` isn't an npm module. It's a local file  that the author of this snippet had beside their `app.js` file. They just screwed up in their blog and didn't post it.