# Socket.io.js not found (node.js + express + socket.io)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I've been checking other related answers such as:

- [node.js /socket.io/socket.io.js not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426882/node-js-socket-io-socket-io-js-not-found)
- [Socket.io not being served by Node.js server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625373/socket-io-not-being-served-by-node-js-server)
- [socket.io.js not found on client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361974/socket-io-js-not-found-on-client)
- [Configuring 'simplest' node.js + socket.IO + Express server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428162/configuring-simplest-node-js-socket-io-express-server)

But I didn't find the solution to my problem.

This is exactly what I did:

Installed node through the windows executable and then:

```
express node6 --hogan --ejs 
cd node6
npm install
npm install socket.io

npm start
```

My app.js is the default one but I added the following lines to link it with socket.io:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.listen(http);
http.listen(3000);
```

[Here's the complete app.js file](http://pastebin.com/Xy0Mm4YG).

I also tried to copy and paste the examples for **Node http server** and **Using with Express 3/4** or the app.js detailed [in the socket.io docs](http://socket.io/docs/), but both of them throw errors when calling `npm start`.

Then, in my hoggn view, I'm trying to load socket.io this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

As far as I know, node.js should get it automatically, but it doesn't in my case. Why?
Express version: 4.2.0

This is the error page:

> Not Found
>   404
>   Error: Not Found 
>       at Layer.app.use.res.render.message [as handle] (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\node6\app.js:29:15)
>       at trim_prefix (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\node6\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:240:15) 
>       at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\node6\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:208:9
>       at Function.proto.process_params (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\node6\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:269:12)
>       at next (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\node6\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:199:19)
>       at next (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\node6\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:176:38)
>       at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\node6\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:137:5
>       at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\node6\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:250:10
>       at next (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\node6\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:160:14)
>       at next (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\node6\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:176:38)

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: File not found? 404 for socket.io.js

Comment: @lombausch updated question with the error log.

Comment: and do you actually have the file in the path?

Comment: @lombausch that path doesn't exists physically. Not in any of the examples I've seen either.

Comment: if it does not exist is your server able to resolve the request?

Comment: @lombausch the node server takes care of it as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing `npm install socket.io` you have to do `npm install socket.io --save` so the socket.io module gets installed in your web development folder (run this command at the base location/where your index.html or index.php is). This installs socket.io to the area in which the command is run, not globally, and, in addition, it automatically corrects/updates your package.json file so node.js knows that it is there.

Then change your source path from `'/socket.io/socket.io.js'` to `'http://' + location.hostname + ':3000/socket.io/socket.io.js'`.

Comment: --save updates dependencies in package.json the module is saved in the exact same location and IMHO it has nothing to do with his problem.

Comment: Look at the second part of the answer, he was not setting the path for the socket.io source correctly.